# CFML form will not insert into SQL Server 2014 database

Tags: sql-server, forms, coldfusion, cfml

Lucee 5.2, SQL Server 2014

I have a form that will not insert a new record into my SQL Server 2014 database.

I've studied this problem for a couple of days and nights and cannot figure out what is going on. I do not get an error message of any kind. I fill out the form, click the Submit button, and I am returned to a blank form. No record is inserted into the database table.

I have tested this abridged version of my code, below, but I still get the same result: no insert happens; and Lucee does not give me back any error message at all.

```
<!--- set a default value "" for RegisterID in scope URL --->
<cfparam name="url.RegisterID" default="">

<!--- define the RegisterID in scope FORM, then set form.RegisterID equal to the RegisterID passed in the URL --->
<cfparam name="form.RegisterID" default="#url.RegisterID#">

<!--- set default values for other user-editable fields --->
<cfparam name="form.Title" default="">
<cfparam name="form.x_first_name" default="">
<cfparam name="form.DateCreated" default="">
<cfparam name="form.DateModified" default="">

<!--- query editRegister tells Lucee which record to edit--->
<cfquery datasource="nnvawi" name="editRegister">
SELECT RegisterID
,Title
,x_first_name
,DateCreated
FROM NNVAWIRegister
WHERE RegisterID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#val(form.RegisterID)#">
</cfquery>


<cftry>  
<cfset variables.error = ""> 

<cfif IsDefined("FORM.doSave")>

<!--- when a RegisterID Exists, the action is UPDATE --->

<cfif val(form.RegisterID)>

<!--- query UpdateUser updates a page record in content table --->
            <cfquery name="UpdateUser" datasource="nnvawi">
                  UPDATE NNVAWIRegister
                  SET
Title = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#Trim(Left(form.Title,50))#">,
x_first_name = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#Trim(Left(form.x_first_name,255))#">,
DateModified = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_timestamp" value="#now()#">
WHERE RegisterID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#val(form.RegisterID)#">
            </cfquery>


<!--- CFELSE: if RegisterID does not exist, then create new Page --->
                <cfelse> 

<!--- query to insert new user record into content table --->
            <cfquery name="InsertRecord" datasource="nnvawi" result="newRegistrant">
                 INSERT INTO NNVAWIRegister
                        (
,Title
,x_first_name
,DateCreated
                        )                   

                 VALUES(
<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#Trim(Left(form.Title,50))#">,
<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#Trim(Left(form.x_first_name,255))#">,
<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_timestamp" value="#now()#">
)         
                    </cfquery>


<!--- use the result attribute value (newRegistrant) to set form field value --->
      <cfset form.RegisterID = newRegistrant.IDENTITYCOL>

<!--- END cfif val(form.RegisterID) -- if a record needed to be updated or added, then it was done --->
                        </cfif>
                    </cfif>
            <cfcatch type="Any">
                 <cfset variables.error = cfcatch.message>
            </cfcatch>
            </cftry>     
<cfif len(variables.error) eq '0'>

            <cfloop index="aCol" list="#editRegister.columnList#">
                   <cfset "form.#aCol#" = editRegister[aCol][editRegister.currentRow]>
              </cfloop>

</cfif>


<cfinclude template="/admin/admin_header.cfm">


<!--- if there an error, display error in readable form --->

<cfif len(variables.error)> 
      <cfoutput>
        <div class="errorbox">#variables.error#</div>
        </cfoutput>

   <br />

             <div class="align-center">
               <input type=button value="Go Back" onClick="history.go(-1)">
             </div>

             <cfabort>
</cfif>



<cfparam name="url.cftoken" default="">

<cfif len(url.cftoken)> 

<div class="center"><button class="medium green"><i class="fa fa-check-square"></i> Update succeeded. Good work!</button></div>

</cfif>

<cfoutput>
<form method="post" name="ebwebworkForm" class="ebwebworkForm">

  <ul>
        <li>
<legend><h2>Registration Details</h2></legend>
      </li>

<input type="hidden" name="RegisterID" value="#form.RegisterID#" /><!--- Embed RegisterID (PK) to assign a value to it --->

<li>
<label for="Title"><h3>Title (Ms., Mr., Dr. etc.):</h3></label>
<input type="text" name="Title" placeholder="Title" value="#Trim(Left(form.Title,255))#" maxlength="255" tabindex="1" size="70" autofocus="true" />
</li>

<li>
<label for="x_first_name"><h3>First Name:</h3></label>
<input type="text" name="x_first_name" placeholder="First Name" value="#Trim(Left(form.x_first_name,255))#" maxlength="255" tabindex="2" size="70" required="yes" />
        <span class="form_hint">Enter First Name</span>
</li>


    <li>
<div class="submitButton">

   <button name="doSave" type="submit" class="green" tabindex="19">Save Record</button>

</div>  
</li>

    </ul>

</form>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you get any error messages? You should reduce your script's code to a simple test case instead of posting a wall of code.

Comment: Dear Sebastian, I have clarified the problem and reduced the amount of posted code. Sorry about posting the full code. I have tried testing the application with just a few fields, as per the CFML code above. I still get the same result. I'm very grateful for any ideas. Thanks so much. Eric

Comment: Reducing the code into a small test case is a good troubleshooting practice in general, not just for posting on S.O.  By removing *all* extraneous bits (css, html, extra queries, ...) it is much easier to identify the problem code.  Also, always comment out try/catch code when troubleshooting, so any errors are visible. Here's the code above reduced by about 2/3: https://trycf.com/gist/c0e431783cd956d6a94607fb21fe3f2e/lucee5?theme=monokai . (Would post it as an edit, but it would almost surely be rejected on review as being too drastic a change.)

Comment: Ageax -- thank you, again. This is very useful information and I have made a note of it. Wishing you a great day. Eric

Answer (score 6):

Your INSERT SQL is invalid. The list of values starts with a comma, that means `Title` must not be preceded by a comma.

The reason you don't see an error message is that the queries are wrapped into a `<cftry>`/`<cfcatch>` block. Within the `<cfcatch>` there is a `<cfset variables.error = cfcatch.message>`, though the actual error message is stored in `cfcatch.detail`. So it is not output.

Comment: Sebastian, that was it! Wow. I've been staring at this code for three days.

That was the only problem. I wish Lucee would have given me more feedback about that.

I was trying to work with CFDUMP but did not get any helpful information from that, either.

Thank you so much for helping me with this. I'm very grateful.

Eric

Comment: I'm happy I could help! Feel free to upvote/accept the answer. :-) If you put the CFDUMP into the CFCATCH block or remove the CFTRY/CFCATCH, you can see the error. Normally it's fine to set CFDUMPs followed by CFABORTs or use a step debugger to see what's going on.

Comment: Dear Sebastian,

Your answer solved my problem. It seems like StackOverflow will not let me Upvote. Perhaps I do not have enough presence or credibility yet. (?) I'm also not seeing, in the interface, a place that lets me accept your answer. I am continuing to hunt around. Anyway, you really helped me. Thank you again. Eric

Comment: Yeah, [vote up requires 15+](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges), almost there.  You should see a grey outline of a check mark next to the answer. Click it to accept the answer and it turns green (might be a delay in how soon after posting you can do that though ... ).